# Testing arrow key keyboard navigation of a radio button group

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using `testing-library` to test an implementation of a radio button group. I can test that `tab` sets focus to the first radio option, but I can't get the arrow key navigation to test properly.

Here's the test I have:

```js
import {
  getByLabelText,
  render,
} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
...

test('arrow key navigation', () => {
  const {container} = render(
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="apple">
        Apple
        <input type="radio" value="apple" id="apple" name="fruit"/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="banana">
        Banana
        <input type="radio" value="banana" id="banana" name="fruit"/>
      </label>
    </div>
  )

  const apple = getByLabelText(container, 'Apple')
  const banana = getByLabelText(container, 'Banana')

  userEvent.tab()
  expect(apple).toHaveFocus() // This assertion passes
  userEvent.keyboard('{arrowright}')
  expect(banana).toHaveFocus() // This assertion fails
})
```

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution Adam?

Comment: @MaciejWojsław I just added a solution that worked for me. Using `.type` instead of `.keyboard` seemed to be the trick

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work using `userEvent.type` and not `.keyboard`. This works for me:

```js
userEvent.tab();
expect(apple).toHaveFocus();
userEvent.type(apple, '{arrowright}');
expect(banana).toHaveFocus();
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue and using `.type` instead of `.keyboard` didn't fix it for me. I'm hoping there's a difference in some package version or configuration, but I'm out of ideas.

If you have a minute to spare, I have a clean reproduction repo here.
https://github.com/a7sc11u/rtl-radios-help/blob/main/src/radios.test.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same situation here, I found out the component didn't rerender which it should be, that's the reason why the test fail

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31043177)

Answer (score 0):

Any user.action is asynchronous

You need to add async and await. See below

```
test('arrow key navigation', async () => {
  const {container} = render(
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="apple">
        Apple
        <input type="radio" value="apple" id="apple" name="fruit"/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="banana">
        Banana
        <input type="radio" value="banana" id="banana" name="fruit"/>
      </label>
    </div>
  )

  const apple = getByLabelText(container, 'Apple')
  const banana = getByLabelText(container, 'Banana')

  await userEvent.tab()
  expect(apple).toHaveFocus() // This assertion passes
  await userEvent.keyboard('{arrowright}')
  expect(banana).toHaveFocus() // This assertion fails
})
```

I just spent half a day debugging before remembering. Hope this helps!